# How should I go ahead and check mobile data connectivity

Tags: java, android, networking, toast

I need a message to show up if there is no internet connection. Currently, if wifi is turn off then the toast method will work and won't move forward. However, if i turn on my mobile data even without a service plan, it will still open a blank activity.

here is the code i got from here

```
public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context)
{
    NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (info == null)
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"no internet connection");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if(info.isConnected())
        {
            Log.d(TAG," internet connection available...");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG," internet connection");
            return true;
        }
```

and this below is in my onClick method.

```
newsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override


        public void onClick(View view) {


if(CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(MainActivity.this)) //returns true if internet available
            {

                moveToNews();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please Check Your Internet Connection and Try Again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG*4000).show();
            }
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `else` return false when `isConnected` is `false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check my below code

[1].Add below line **internet permission into AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

[2]. On your **MainActivity** or Parent activity from you want to display or going to next activity add below code

[2.1] Globally declare below **variable**

```
private boolean isInternetConnected;
```

[2.2] add below line into onCreate()

```
isInternetConnected = isNetworkConnected(getApplicationContext());
```

[2.3] add below **method**

```
public boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context)
    {
        if(context != null)
        {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (cm != null) {
                NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (ni == null) {
                    return false;
                } else
                    return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

[3]. add below code into onCreate() below of this line i`sInternetConnected = isNetworkConnected(getApplicationContext());`

```
if(isInternetConnected){
  //Move to another Activity or display Toast
}
else{
  //Toast of not connected with Internet 
}
```

**THAT'S IT ;)!!**

Answer (score 1):

To check internet connection -

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
}
```

In Menifest file -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```